# If meta_key exists then don't select this post?

Tags: posts, post-meta, mysql, sql

I'm trying to select all posts EXCEPT ones with a meta_key `somekey`.

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_posts JOIN wp_postmeta
ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
WHERE meta_key != 'somekey'
```

But this is still selecting that post, because other meta_keys still match.

Basically, the effect I want is to enter a custom field named 'somekey', and then that post will not be selected.

Comment: Why are you running a custom SQL query when you can use `WP_Query` to do the same faster

Comment: I need to do it with SQL, this is a snippet from a more complex query that I can't do with WP_Query

Comment: Then it is advisable to post your **complete** query. What is it exactly what this query should do. Please answer this in the form of an [edit] to your question

Comment: Right... cus adding more code is going to make the question clearer... I narrowed it down on purpose to the relevant part.

Comment: Suite yourself. Did you read the answer from @Milo. The solution **depends on your actual query**. This was my assesment as well, that is why I asked to see your complete query.

Comment: That's only because he read these comments. This question is self contained, it doesn't matter if it's part of another query or not, it should still work the same. The point is that I need to do it with SQL and not WP_Query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways you could do it- `NOT IN`, `NOT EXISTS`, `IS NULL`. Which method is best depends on your actual query.

```
SELECT *
FROM $wpdb->posts LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta
ON $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id
AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'somekey'
WHERE $wpdb->postmeta.post_id IS NULL
```